# Confusion in the Maclaurin's expansion of cos$x$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, trigonometry, taylor-expansion

In my text book the Maclaurin's expansion with Lagrange's form of remainder of cosx is written as, $$\cos x = 1 - \frac{1}{2!}x^2 + \frac{1}{4!}x^4 + \dotsm + \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n} + \frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{(2n+2)!}x^{2n+2} \cos \theta x$$ $0<\theta<1$.

I don't understand why we need to write the $(2n+2)^{th}$ power of $x$ in the expansion. Can't we just write as,
$$\cos x = 1 - \frac{1}{2!}x^2 + \frac{1}{4!}x^4 + \dotsm + \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n)!}x^{2n}\cos \theta x$$

What is wrong here?

Comment: There is nothing wrong... They are just two different approximations that differ by the inclusion of one term.

Comment: If you let $n = k - 1$ then $2n+2 = 2k$, showing it makes no difference.